# How to count the "kABPersonBirthdayProperty" in Addressbook?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I working with the Addressbook for dipslaying the contacts list then count the number of names, phone numbers, emails, dates (like DOB, Anniversary date..etc). I using the "ABMultiValueRef" class for assign the fields then counting also. In this phone numbers, emails, names are count successfully & work's fine but i did not count the birthday date class. it will crash the code. Here is my code for date of birth.

```
         ABMultiValueRef dateofbirth1 = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
        **NSLog(@"Date Count: %lu",ABMultiValueGetCount(dateofbirth1));**  //the code crashes here.
         **if(ABMultiValueGetCount(dateofbirth1)>0)** //crashed
       {
             //
        }
```

How can i count the date of birth details. can any one help me?. I tired with the "kABPersonDateProperty" also.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if dateofbirth1 != nil and only if its not nil you have to try to get its count. May be some contacts dotting have this value set and so dateofbirth1 could be nil and you are trying to use a nil Core foundation object which leads to a crash

Comment: Thank You pradeep. ya, u said right , i receive the nill value. so only it crashed.i will try to change. Thanks